# getting Json result in Android

Tags: android, json

Json Problem :

I have this formatted JSON

```
 {
 "Table1":[
  {
     "TableName":"LoadDistributor",
     "Description":"Distributor ",
     "MandatoryFlag":"1",
     "Status":"",
     "Priority":"0"
  },
  {
     "TableName":"LoadPrice",
     "Description":"Price ",
     "MandatoryFlag":"1",
     "Status":"",
     "Priority":"0"
  },
  {
     "TableName":"LoadProduct",
     "Description":"Product ",
     "MandatoryFlag":"1",
     "Status":"",
     "Priority":"0"
  },
  {
     "TableName":"RD.AlternativeProductDetail",
     "Description":"AltProdutDetail",
     "MandatoryFlag":"0",
     "Status":"",
     "Priority":"0"
  },
  {
     "TableName":"XA.vwTown",
     "Description":"Town ",
     "MandatoryFlag":"1",
     "Status":"",
     "Priority":"0"
  }
```

]
}

Android Json Processing method is:

```
   public String[] getStringArrayResponseJson(SoapPrimitive node, ArrayList<String> strings) {
    try{

        String result = node.toString();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        // Parsing
        JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
        JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
        Log.i("@@@" , "===="+  valArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < valArray.length(); i++) {
            strings.add(valArray.getString(i));
        }

        json.put("sample key", "sample value");
        Log.i("REST", "<jsonobject>\n" + json.toString()
                + "\n</jsonobject>");
    }catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My requirement is I want to get the TableName into string[] or list... How we can do this?

Please help me what is the error in my json processing method:?

Comment: You want to get all TableName fields in a string array? Only this field?

Comment: Thanks Pepi. yes. Need to get all table name.It is working fine now according to David Olsson answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code, not sure that its going to work. 
I create an ArrayList for the strings just for the sake of it.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Table1");        
int max = array.length();
 for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
   JSONObject tmp = array.getJSONObject(i);
   list.add(tmp.getString("TableName"));
 }
```

Might be a quicker way but just for an example.

You could read more http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/