# File not found: On WIFI is totally OK, but on 3G I have an exception

Tags: java, android, json

My android app is set for minSdkVersion="16" targetSdkVersion="17". I use the following code.

```
URL urlLinkSource = new URL("XXXX");
                urlLinkSourceReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlLinkSource.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.configure(
                        DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                        false);
                dataContainerListLightData = mapper.readValue(urlLinkSourceReader,
                        new TypeReference<List<DataContainerListLight>>() {
                        });
```

For reading my JSON data. The main problem is that everything is working fine when I use WIFI, when I switch only to 3G connection I have next exception:

```
03-14 14:06:22.349: W/System.err(7578): java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

In fact I have 2 JSON sources for processing. Is there some pool connection limit or other restrictions for pure 3G connection without WIFI? The exact place of my exception is urlLinkSource.openStream() (the logs are speaking it) and I tried on brawser and wifi test - all is working. What is the source of that exception in pure 3G mode?

Comment: nope - the url is internet regular addres

Comment: Could it be by network addressing issues? May be you are using a local network url?

Comment: Have you tried to get the file through any browser or console commands?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open the url in the browser with 3G connection?
It seems that you want to implement a RESTful interface so I recomend you to use the DefaultHttpClient.

Here you can see how to implement such an interface:
[How to get JSON content from a RESTful server to a Android client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611663/how-to-get-json-content-from-a-restful-server-to-a-android-client)